# Finding the volume of weird pyramid

Tags: geometry, determinant, analytic-geometry, solid-geometry

I am given the points $A(4|3|1)$, $B(1|7|1)$, $C(-3|2|0)$, $D(0|0|0)$ and $S(0|3|4)$. I tried splitting this geometric construct up in two different tetrahedrons:
[image]

Using $\overrightarrow{DB}$ as  a diagonal of the quadrilateral , I get that the the volume of the entire geometric construction is $29$. Using $\overrightarrow{AC}$ as diagonal that splits up the construction into two different tetrahedrons, I get $28$ however.

Why is that the case and what is the actual volume?

Comment: Just evaluate two determinants. I got $29$.

Comment: Did you reed the entire question? I get $29$ aswell. But how did you divide it into two different tetrahedrons? When using $\overrightarrow{AC}$, I get $28$.

Comment: There isn't a well-defined polyhedron yet: https://i.imgur.com/HLEGzkX.png. You can choose $ABD$ and $BCD$ to be faces, then you'll get the volume of the convex hull of the five points. But you can also choose $ABC$ and $ACD$ to be faces and compute the volume of the concave polyhedron.

Comment: What does this mean exactly? Isn't the volume enclosed by ABCDS not unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$V=V_{DABS}+V_{DSBC}=\frac{1}{6}\left|\left(\begin{array}{cc}0 & 3 & 4\\4 & 3 & 1\\ 1 & 7 & 1 \end{array}\right)\right|+\frac{1}{6}\left|\left(\begin{array}{cc}0 & 3 & 4\\1 & 7 & 1\\ -3 & 2 & 0 \end{array}\right)\right|=29.$$

If by $V=V_{SABC}+V_{SDBC}$ we'll get another answer, it says that points $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ are not placed in the same plane. Now, just check it!

We have: $$V_{SABC}+V_{SDBC}+V_{ABCD}=V_{DABS}+V_{DSBC},$$ which gives
$$V_{SABC}+V_{SDBC}\neq V_{DABS}+V_{DSBC}$$because $$V_{ABCD}=1.$$

Comment: But what is the actual volume then?

Comment: @ParabolicAlcoholic The volume of the polyhedron is equal to $29$.

Comment: Why is $V_{OABS}+V_{OSBC} \neq V_{SABC}+V_{SOC}$?

Comment: @ParabolicAlcoholic Because $V_{ABCD}=1.$ I fixed a typo...